# Returning array with only minimum and maximum values (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have the task where the array resuslts" should be returned with only two values from all the array: minimum and maximum values. But the code does not do it. What's wrong? Please help me to correct the code in order to return the array with minimum and maximum values. Fill free to clarify or ask additional issues.
By the conditions of the task I have not to use any other methods (Maths or strems). only loops and arrays.

```java
public class Stat {
    public static int[] getStat(int[] results) {
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<results.length;i++){
            if(results[i] < min){
                min = results[i];
            }
            if(results[i] > max) {
                max = results[i];
            }
        }
        return new int[] { min, max };
    }
}
```

Comment: Your minimum value will be 0 if your minimum value in results is 1.  Because 0 is lesser than 1.

Comment: _But the code does not do it._ It does for me. [Edit] your question and post the code that calls method `getStat`. Also post the result that you are getting (or if you are not getting a result or if you are getting an error). And if you are getting a result then write why the result is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you initialize `min` with 0, initially making 0 the lowest number in your array. Try to initialize `min` with the highest possible int value (which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). Likewise, `max` should be initialized with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: When i applied:
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Following mistakes appeared.
Compile error:
/Stat.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
^
  symbol:   variable min
  location: class Stat/Stat.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
By the conditions of the task I have not to use any other methods (Maths or strems). only loops and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize min = Integer.MAX_VALUE and max = Integer.MIN_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static int[] getStat(int[] arr) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int num : arr) {
        min = Math.min(min, num);
        max = Math.max(max, num);
    }

    return new int[] { min, max };
}
```

Or using streams:

```java
public static int[] getStat(int[] arr) {
    int min = Arrays.stream(arr).min().orElse(0);
    int max = Arrays.stream(arr).max().orElse(0);
    return new int[] { min, max };
}
```